# Use exec() with a function that uses summarise with curly-curly

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to run this function with `exec()`. I have a workaround that uses `rlang::expr` and then `!!` but that implies changing the function to accept an expression as an argument instead of a quoted variable. Is there a way to call this function without loosing the ability to pass quoted arguments?

```r
library(tidyverse)

calc_mean <- function(df, col) {
  df %>%
    summarise(mean({{ col }}))
}

#doesn't work
map(list('calc_mean'), ~exec(.x, df = mtcars, col = mpg))
#> Warning in mean.default(~structure(list(manufacturer = c("audi", "audi", :
#> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
#> [[1]]
#>   mean(...)
#> 1        NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

My expected output would be the same as calling the function outside `exec`:

```r
calc_mean(mtcars, mpg)
#>   mean(mpg)
#> 1  20.09062
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect you want to loop over a list of function names and this is just a minimal example (otherwise there would be no need for `map`).

We could use base R `do.call`, but we'd have to `quote` the arguments and put them in a list:

```r
library(tidyverse)

calc_mean <- function(df, col) {
  df %>%
    summarise(mean({{ col }}))
}

map(list("calc_mean"), ~ do.call(.x, list(df = quote(mtcars), col = quote(mpg))))
#> [[1]]
#>   mean(mpg)
#> 1  20.09062
```

Another possible approach is to work with `get` or `mget` (if you have a vector of function names) and then we can do something crazy. We just call `.x` as a function in your lambda function. No `list` or `quote` needed. It is best practice to specify the `envir` argument of `get` which I skipped in the minimal example below:

```r
map(list(get("calc_mean")), ~ .x(df = mtcars, col = mpg))

#> [[1]]
#>   mean(mpg)
#> 1  20.09062
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @TimTeanFan Thank you TimTeaFan. While I understand why this is important I can not imagine in which scenario I will need this. For me now `calc_mean(mtcars, mpg)` is completely sufficient. Could you please give a scenario where I will need this?

Comment: Sure, the scenario is, you want to loop over many functions, at least that is what I expect the OP is going to do. For a minimal example one function is enough but I expect that there will be a list of functions which are being looped over.